# Pandas: Filter rows by | (OR) – not mutually inclusive

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm looking for a way to filter `pandas` rows via alternatives in a string. I have many different terms I would like to search for, so it would be easier to put them in a few variables rather than list them every time I need to access them.

I currently do:

```
df = df[df["A"].str.contains("BULL|BEAR|LONG|SHORT", case=False)]
```

Instead do something like:

```
bull = "BULL|LONG"
bear = "BEAR|SHORT"
leverage = bull + bear

df = df[df["A"].find(leverage, case=False)]
```

The problem is that this method only filters out *one* alternative from each variable. It will find `"BULL"` but not `"LONG"`, and it will find `"SHORT"` but not `"BEAR"`. It seems what it selects is arbitrary. Depending on if and where these terms occur in the file I'm reading from, results may differ.

I am assuming this is due to `|` functions as `OR` which is mutually exclusive.

If so, is there a mutually inclusive option? I would like to continue to use *strings* to do this. The reason is that I use `str.contains` at another place that relies on the same variables:

```
df.loc[df["A"].str.contains(bull, case=False), "B"]
df.loc[df["A"].str.contains(bear, case=False), "B"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to add an additional `'|'` to join your terms:

```
In [227]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['bull', 'bear', 'short', 'null', 'LONG']})
df

Out[227]:
       A
0   bull
1   bear
2  short
3   null
4   LONG

In [228]:    
bull = "BULL|LONG"
bear = "BEAR|SHORT"
leverage = bull + '|' + bear
df = df[df["A"].str.contains(leverage, case=False)]
df

Out[228]:
       A
0   bull
1   bear
2  short
4   LONG
```